# Sending data by nRF24L01 with Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, nrf24l01+

Can I send data using nRF24L01 with Arduino through multiple pipes?
As by using the RF24 library, I can send data through just one pipe and receive on the 6 pipes that nRF24L01 has.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but the nRF24L01 can only transmit one message at at time, since it only has one buffer.

So roughly speaking, for each message

1. Set the transmit pipe address (if different than the last one)
2. Send data
3. Wait for completion (and ack or failure, if in that mode)